# useEffects hook doesn't fire changing a simple state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a component with several different states:

```
const [state1,setState1]=useState(false);
const [state2,setState2]=useState(false);
...
const [staten,setStaten]=useState(false);
```

then I have 2 useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
... do something
}, [state1, state2, staten, .... other stuffs] )


useEffect(() => {
... do some other things
}, [state1, state2, staten, .... other different stuffs] )
```

now, when `staten` is changed (in a child process which have access to `setStaten`,
the system fires only the second 'useEffect' and completely forget the first one.

My assumption is that the system should fire both the 'useEffects' in their lexical order.

I spent two days debugging (it's a mess!) to discover this fact.

Additional information:

1. there hooks are not conditioned
2. all the dependencies are inside the hooks

Any suggestion will be appreciated. TIA.

---------------------- CONSOLE LOG --------------------------------

FIRST ROUND: please, note that there are several UseEffects, and their order is sequential. The one I miss from the first round is the `UseEffect X05`

```
UseEffect X01
Play.js:146 UseEffect X02
Play.js:185 UseEffect X03
Play.js:208 UseEffect X04
Play.js:146 UseEffect X02
Play.js:185 UseEffect X03
Play.js:305 UseEffect X06 - winePath set
Play.js:320 AXIOS: path=http://localhost:3000/.........
Play.js:329 UseEffect X07 - DB READ
Play.js:354 UseEffect X08 - Create Producer And Vendor List
Play.js:379 UseEffect X09 - Set Products Ordered By Mentions
```

The SECOND ROUND is a mess:

Lines with '---------------' are rendered components
And there are a lot of re-render, while I need to render the two components only at the end of the execution of all the effects

Anyway, this second round is when I `setState2("XYZ")` and the `UseEffect X05` and `UseEffect X06` are executed. Correct.

```
Play.js:390 NickSelection-------------
Play.js:418 Market--------------------
Play.js:390 NickSelection-------------
Play.js:418 Market--------------------
Play.js:265 UseEffect X05 - FilteredAvailableWineList 2
Play.js:273 UseEffect X05 - Products filtered
Play.js:390 NickSelection-------------
Play.js:418 Market----------------
Play.js:305 UseEffect X06 - winePath set
Play.js:390 NickSelection---------
Play.js:418 Market----------------
Play.js:320 AXIOS: path=http://localhost:3000/.......
Play.js:329 UseEffect X07 - DB READ
Play.js:379 UseEffect X09 - Set Products Ordered By Mentions
Play.js:390 NickSelection--------
Play.js:418 Market---------------
Play.js:390 NickSelection--------
Play.js:418 Market---------------
Play.js:354 UseEffect X08 - Create Producer And Vendor List
Play.js:379 UseEffect X09 - Set Products Ordered By Mentions
Play.js:390 NickSelection--------
Play.js:418 Market---------------
```

The THIRD ROUND is where I `setState2(false)` **but `UseEffect X05` and `UseEffect X06` are not executed.**

```
Play.js:390 NickSelection--------
Play.js:418 Market---------------
Play.js:354 UseEffect X08 - Create Producer And Vendor List
Play.js:379 UseEffect X09 - Set Products Ordered By Mentions
Play.js:390 NickSelection--------
Play.js:418 Market---------------
Play.js:390 NickSelection--------
Play.js:418 Market---------------
```

Comment: Create a reproducible example. How are you checking if the `useEffect`'s callbacks are being called?

Comment: Put `console.log` in each `useEffect` and check two `console.log` will be executed or not. I think you have mistakes in actions that wrote into `useEffects`

Comment: Really don't know how to create a reproducible example: the whole is part of a complex application connected to a DB